# flutter return future list in a var to use outside the loop

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I'm trying to recuperate the list value of a database.
i can but what i want is to export the result in a var so i can use in all my code just by calling "print(myList);"

this is my code :

```
  static const URL =
  'https://xxxhost/employee_actions3.php';

  static Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees() async {

  try {
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(
    URL,
  ));
  print("getEmployees >> Response:: ${response.body}");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       List<Employee> list = parsePhotos(response.body);
    
    
      return list;
    
  } else {
      throw <Employee>[];
  }
  } catch (e) {
    return <Employee>[];
  }
 }
```

and my classe Employee

```
 class Employee {
 String id;
 String firstName;
 String lastName;

 Employee({required this.id, required this.firstName, required  this.lastName});

 factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return Employee(
     id: json['id'] as String,
     firstName: json['lat'] as String,
     lastName: json['lng'] as String,
   );
 }
 }
```

can i have help please ?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to access async data in most modern languages, including `dart`, they are:

**1. By providing a callback then**

**2. By using the function in an async context and awaiting the result**

I've wrapped the code above in a class called API so the examples below are easier to follow,

```dart
class API {
  static const URL = 'https://xxxhost/employee_actions3.php';

  static Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(URL));
      print("getEmployees >> Response:: ${response.body}");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<Employee> list = parsePhotos(response.body);
        return list;
      } else {
        throw("${response.statusCode} Failed to parse photos");
      }
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

**Method 1:** Providing a callback to `.then`, this method will allow you to work with `async` actions in a synchronous context, but be aware it will not halt the execution flow.

```dart
void main() {
  API.getEmployees().then((resp) => print(resp)).catchError(e) => print(e);
}
```

**Method 2:** Async/Await, this method will allow you to access the data inline, that is `var x = await myAsyncFunc()` remember the await keyword requires the function to be called within an `async` context. And the await keyword will halt the execution flow till the `future` completes.

```dart
void main() async {
  try {
    final list = await API.getEmployees();
    print(list);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Using either one of the two methods outlined above will allow you to access the data of the list later on.

**Additional Reading:**

[Async programming in dart](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

[Futures and error handling](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling#the-future-api-and-callbacks)

Comment: hello thank you to respon but what i want is just to transform the value of the return list in a var...if i test print(list) it say "undefined name list"...

Comment: what do you mean by "transform the value of the return list in a var"

Comment: just export the return value in a string ... so i can call print(list);...

Comment: okay, I understand, I will update my answer in some time...and leave a comment. However it is suggested to use the methods given above.

Comment: it will such a good day if you could help me to find this ...thank you in advances.