# Firebase.initializeApp() -- How do I know that this requires an await async functionality?

Tags: firebase, flutter

This code is from: https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/

```
void registerNotification() async {
  // 1. Initialize the Firebase app
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // 2. Instantiate Firebase Messaging
  _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  .......
}
```

Here for `Firebase.initializeApp()` they have used await and async.
How do I know await is required for this function to work properlty?

Doc are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase#initializeapp
I didn't see anything special mentioned regarding await in docs.

Comment: When working with Futures async/await is one option available to you, depending on the situation you can choose to use it. Check the answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151576/flutter-return-future-list-in-a-var-to-use-outside-the-loop/68151820#68151820) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you've pointed out is for Node.js, [here's](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initializing-flutterfire) a link to the FlutterFire's "Getting Started" docs. There it says:

> To initialize FlutterFire, call the initializeApp method on the Firebase class:
>
> `await Firebase.initializeApp();`
>
> The method is asynchronous and returns a Future, so you need to ensure it has completed before displaying your main application.

It is common that "initialize" functions are Futures, and thus should be awaited for. You can check that by looking at the return type of the function, which is documented [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/Firebase/initializeApp.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here is the implementation for `initializeApp()` which you can find in the [documentation from `firebase_core`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_core/latest/firebase_core/Firebase/initializeApp.html):

```dart
static Future<FirebaseApp> initializeApp({
  String? name,
  FirebaseOptions? options,
}) async {
  FirebaseAppPlatform app = await _delegate.initializeApp(
    name: name,
    options: options,
  );

  return FirebaseApp._(app);
}
```

As you can see the return type is a `Future<FirebaseApp>` which means that it is an asynchronous method and that you should use the keyword `await` to ensure your operation will be completed before continuing to execute your code.
As you might already know `await` can only be used inside an `async` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can click inside the function to see what's behind the scene
For example, I've clicked it and here's the result

[image]

so It returns Future of FirebaseApp which is required async and await to get the value inside of the Future