# Flutter pushing two page to navigator sequentially

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I want to push two pages to the flutter navigator one after another, so that going back from 2nd page redirects me to the first page. The code for this action will look somewhat like below -

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FirstPage.PATH);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondPage.PATH);
```

The above code works fine. But my confusion is, will it work always as the pushNamed function is asynchronous as it returns a future value. So it could happen that the second page got pushed to navigator before the first page.

The ideal implementation seems to me to wait for the first call to pushNamed return its value and then call the second one. But strangely the following two solutions don't work. The first page did get pushed but it doesn't push the second page.

Solution 1(Not working):

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              FirstPage.PATH.then((_) => 
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondPage.PATH));
```

Solution 2(Not working):

```
await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FirstPage.PATH);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondPage.PATH);
```

Can anyone please clarify what I'm thinking wrong? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Why do you want to push a page at once? What is page one for?

Comment: Check the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151576/flutter-return-future-list-in-a-var-to-use-outside-the-loop/68151820#68151820) for an explanation of the difference between Solution 1 and Solution 2

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can pass a callback to pageA, add animation listener and call this callback when animation is finished.

this is full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
      routes: {
        'pageA': (context) => PageA(),
        'pageB': (context) => PageB(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _onPressed,
          child: Text('press me'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPressed() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageA.routeName, arguments: _pushNextPage);
  }

  void _pushNextPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(PageB.routeName);
  }
}

class PageA extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = 'pageA';

  @override
  _PageAState createState() => _PageAState();
}

class _PageAState extends State<PageA> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation?.addStatusListener(_statusListener);
    });
  }

  void _statusListener(AnimationStatus status) {
    if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
      final route = ModalRoute.of(context);
      route?.animation?.removeStatusListener(_statusListener);
      final callback = route?.settings.arguments as VoidCallback;
      callback.call();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('PAGE A')));
}

class PageB extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = 'pageB';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('PAGE B')));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solutions do not work, because the `Future` returned by `pushNamed` is only completed when the page is removed from the navigation stack again.

So in your examples, the second page is pushed, once the first page has been closed.

I don't think it can happen, that the second page will be pushed *before* the first page in this example:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(FirstPage.PATH);
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(SecondPage.PATH);
```

This should be a valid solution for what you want to achieve.